# Which of the following abelian groups are cyclic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Given the abelian groups of order $7425$:

$$Z_{33} \times Z_{15} \times Z_{15} , \ Z_{25} \times Z_{297} , \  Z_{45} \times Z_{165} , Z_{55}\times Z_9 \times Z_{15}$$

- Which of these groups, if any, are isomorphic?
- Which groups are cyclic?
- How can one write these group as a product of cyclic groups of *prime-power* order.

---

I found that $Z_{25} \times Z_{297}$ is cyclic while the others are not. I'm not sure which are isomorphic.

Comment: I found Z25×Z297 cyclic while others not .I'm not sure which isomorphic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with this lemma (or can prove it): If $n$ and $m$ are coprime, then $Z_{nm}=Z_n\times Z_m$ (where equality stands for isomorphism).

Using this lemma you can decompose all of your groups to products of cyclic groups of prime power order.
For example,
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_{33}\times Z_{15}\times Z_{15}
&=&
Z_{3\cdot11}\times Z_{3\cdot5}\times Z_{3\cdot5}
\\&=&
Z_3\times Z_{11}\times Z_3\times Z_5\times Z_3\times Z_5.
\end{eqnarray}
From here you can recognize that this group has a noncyclic subgroup $Z_3\times Z_3$, so the group itself is not cyclic.

A product of cyclic groups of coprime orders is cyclic, as is easy to check.
With these tools you can answer question 2.

To answer question 1, you can use a  converse of the lemma I stated at the beginning.
But there is also a more direct way now that you have explicit groups.
If two groups have the same decomposition (as in your last question), they are isomorphic.
But for example $Z_5\times Z_5\neq Z_{25}$ because only one of these groups has an element of order 25.

Can you solve your problem and check your results with these ideas?

---

**Addendum:**
With the method I described you get
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_{33}\times Z_{15}\times Z_{15}
&=&
Z_3\times Z_{11}\times Z_3\times Z_5\times Z_3\times Z_5,\\
Z_{25}\times Z_{297}
&=&
Z_{25}\times Z_{27}\times Z_{11},\\
Z_{45}\times Z_{165}
&=&
Z_5\times Z_9\times Z_3\times Z_5\times Z_{11}\quad\text{and}\\
Z_{55}\times Z_9\times Z_{15}
&=&
Z_5\times Z_{11}\times Z_9\times Z_3\times Z_5.
\end{eqnarray}
Using the ideas I gave above, one can see that the second one is the only cyclic group, so others are not isomorphic to it.
Compare the decompositions of the last two groups: What do you notice?
Compare the first and the third group: Which one of these has elements of order 9?

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get isomorphism can you help on this please.I found all not cyclic except z25×Z297.

Comment: @MAlrantisi, I added something to help with the isomorphism problem. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank joonas .it's a great help I found that first and third are isomorphic also 3 and 4 are isomorphic depending on same structure decomposing

Comment: @MAlrantisi, the third and fourth group are indeed isomorphic, but the first one is not isomorphic to them. (Look at the hint regarding elements of order 9. There is a difference in this property, so the groups are not isomorphic.) Anyway, I was glad to be of service!

Comment: Thanks its been a fabulous service you gave.and I understand it now